# Embedded videos don't show up

Tags: php, html, youtube

I have a web site I'm working on and for some reason some of my videos don't display.  The first videos display but the next one's don't.

So first one looks like this:

[image: Displays first one]

And the rest look like this:

[image: Rest look like this]

I know the url's I am using are correct, I dump them to the screen and navigated to them to make sure they weren't broken.  This is in chrome, same thing happens in IE.

This is the code I am using to embed:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" alt="Jesus Culture" src="<?=$row?>" 
frameborder="5" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Have you checked if your $row variable is being set correctly?

Comment: Yes, at the bottom I say that I dumped them to screen, and checked them.

Comment: Please, provide the generated code. Without knowing exactly what is being generated, it's not possible to guess why it's not showing up.

Comment: Hey can you display the processed html content out here

Comment: It has nothing to do with generated code, if I hard code a url into the iframe it still doesn't display..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using similar code to yours for multiple videos on one page,
i.e.

```
<iframe width="425" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/video-code" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Make sure that your urls have the embed format. Also try to place the src value hardcoded (no php) to check whether in that case displaying multiple videos on the page will be an issue.

Comment: ahh that makes sense, I was just copy pasting urls, didn't realize the embed url was different, thanks.